# Android memory stuck

Tags: ram

Once my phone froze and reboot by itself and then I notice all apps and every change i made went back in time :D. After few tries and reboots i decided to wipe all data it gave me this error:

```
-- mkdir /data/app/ fail. err is -1
```

I tried everything, even recording clean image by HDDRawCopy but it still goes back to this one state. I have no idea what I can do and what kind of magic is this. Do you know how to fix it or even what is it?

Answer (score 0):

mkdir is a command that is intended to create a directory. The /data/app/ folder is an integral part of your android OS which practically stores all of your apps data. The fact that this command failed likely means your partition wasn't formatted appropriately as such the OS doesn't have permission to write to it. The only solution I'd advice is performing a factory reset/wipe data from recovery menu.Most android devices recovery menu are accessible through the following method

1. press the VOLUME UP + HOME + POWER buttons all the same time and
   HOLD THEM DOWN
2. release only the POWER button when the device vibrates
3. release the other buttons when the ANDROID SYSTEM RECOVERY screen
   appears
4. using the VOLUME DOWN / UP buttons to navigate, select WIPE CACHE
   PARTITION
   Then navigate to the wipe data/factory reset

   For more information on different android partitions read [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/android-partitions-explained-boot-system-recovery-data-cache-misc/)

Comment: I actually got this error on recovery, also I OVERWROTE whole memory, i found somebody else posted image of clean system so I kinda changed every bit of memory in the phone, but it seems it didn't work at all although the program said all succeded

EDIT: I don't know maybe it's some kind of virus that does it, but it's really weird that I can't even brick this phone, cause everything excluding external-memory keeps going to one state, although phone seems working, just freezes sometimes and reboots causing all data to go to "the state" ;)